# FirebaseListAdapter alphabetical order

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

In my Android app, I have a ListView with a `FirebaseListAdapter` that shows me my users, now I want the firebaseListAdapter to be sort in alphabetical order. How can I achieve this?

Code:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        String.class,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        databaseReference
                ){
                    @Override
                    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

                        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        textView.setText(model);

                    }
                };

mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on what the name is. If you store the users under their name (so that the name is the key):

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
    this,
    String.class,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    databaseReference.orderByKey()
){
```

But if for example you have the name as a property called "name", you'd use:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
    this,
    String.class,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    databaseReference.orderByChild("name")
){
```

Finally: if you want to order by the single string value of the keys:

```
FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
    this,
    String.class,
    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
    databaseReference.orderByValue()
){
```

Comment: Actually, the Key is a random generated key, so none of the above actually fits my case I think..

Comment: I think you'll need the second snippet in that case. If not, you'll have to expand your question (there's an edit link under it) to include the information on what "sort alphabetical" means.

Comment: I already found out with the help of your answer! instead of .orderByKey(), you an just use .orderByValue().. Thanks!

Comment: MaartenWeyns if you found the solution because of @FrankvanPuffelen answer, then you should give him credit...

Comment: @MaartenWeyns: aha. I don't see a lot of usage of `orderByValue()` so had not included that snippet. I added it now.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

Here is the working code:

```
mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

FirebaseListAdapter<String> firebaseListAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<String>(
                        this,
                        String.class,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        databaseReference.orderByValue()
                ){
                    @Override
                    protected void populateView(View v, String model, int position) {

                        TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                        textView.setText(model);

                    }
                };

mListView.setAdapter(firebaseListAdapter);
```